# Unreachable remote address in Apache Spark

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I’m trying to setup a cluster using Apache Spark 1.4.1 in 3 Ubuntu machines (named cloud-server-3 to 5). I have created my own clusters using Spark before but this time I can’t seem to get it running.

I did the following for each machine.

- Downloaded the last prebuilt version of Spark with Hadoop 2.6, placed
  it in /var/www/spark and added SPARK_HOME to environment variables.
- Installed the openjdk-7-jdk and added JAVA_HOME to environment variables.
- Shared the SSH keys between every machine using ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id.
- Created the conf/spark-env.sh file with the master IP and the local IP in every machine.

And now the problems start.
I can create masters and slaves in every machine and can create a master in a machine and a slave in the same machine by using its name, IP or just localhost and connect them. But I can’t connect different machines.

The weirdest thing is that if I put my slaves in the conf/slaves file and run start-all.sh where I want the master, the master goes up it starts the worker on the other machine but then the worker can’t connect back to the master. I keep getting for master in cloud-server-3 and slave in cloud-server-5

"15/08/20 18:48:01 INFO Worker: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@cloud-server-3:7077/user/Master...

15/08/20 18:48:01 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@cloud-server-3:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters"

I tried disabling the firewalls, confirmed that the machines can ping each other, confirmed that I can SSH every machine without password and edited /etc/hosts and added the IPs and names of every machine. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Can u do a telnet on ports like 7077??

Comment: Can you add your master logs.  What does it say around "Remoting started; listening on addresses ..." ?

Comment: I cant to this now  since the computers are connected only to intranet where I work. The master said that we had been elected master or something like that and that cluster was alive.
@Nipun, the master logs said that the master was listening on port 7077 and the same port appeared on the localhost:8080 page and netstat.
To both of you,  the day after I posted this I arrived at work I turn on the computers and every thing was working and it kept working until I left. I have no idea what happened. Thank you for spending your time trying to help me. You guys are awesome :)